# Building Hadoop 1.2.1 with Maven

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I have been using Hadoop 1.2.1 from recent past. I wanted to add my own functionality to Hadoop-common. However, the docs for building the hadoop source and developing are available only for latest versions of Hadoop. I was able to compile the release 2.4.0 with Maven by following the tutorial. But now I wanted to compile my 1.2.1. And that doesn't seem to be a maven project at all. There are no pom.xmls.

So if anyone has done that before, and if you could share the steps / web links for developing 1.2.1 branch, I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I have to change something in hadoop source and recompile it, but I cannot find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your pom.xml, inside your project tag:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I believe the OP is looking to download and compile his own version of hadoop, like a 99999-SNAPSHOT version. :)